# The Kostka-Foulkes polynomial in terms of the weak-order on standard tableaux

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

J. Nzeutchap offers an interesting interpretation of the Kostka numbers in his paper "On the Young-Fibonacci Insertion Algorithm" (see the link https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.1969), namely:

If $T_1$ and $T_2$ are two standard tableaux each with $n$ boxes (but possibly of different shape) declare that $T_1 \preceq T_2$ if and only if there exist two permutations $\tau_1, \tau_2 \in S_n$ such that $\tau_1 \leq \tau_2$ in weak order and the insertion tableau $P(\tau_i)$ coincides with $T_i$ for $i=1,2$. Furthermore, given a partition $\mu \vdash n$ let $rT_\mu$ denote the *row canonical standard tableau* of shape $\mu$ (see page 17 of Nzeutchap for a definition). Note that $\widehat{\scriptstyle 0}:= rT_{(n)}$ will be the minimal standard tableaux with respect to this induced weak ordering $\preceq$ on the set of all standard Young tableaux with $n$ boxes.

According to theorem 7.2 of Nzeutchap's paper the Kostka number $K_{\lambda, \mu}$ associated to a pair of partitions $\lambda, \mu \vdash n$
counts the number of tableaux of shape $\lambda$ within the interval $\big[\widehat{\scriptstyle 0} \, , \, rT_\mu\big]$ with respect to
the induced weak order $\preceq$.

**Question:** Is it possible to read off the Kostka-Foulkes polynomial $K_{\lambda, \mu}(t)$ in terms of some statistic on the standard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$ which inhabit this weak order interval $\big[\widehat{\scriptstyle 0} \, , \, rT_\mu\big]$ ?

thanks, ines.

**Remark:** The Kostka-Foulkes polynomial $K_{\lambda, 1^n}$ is
given essentially by the $t$-hook formula, specifically

\begin{equation}
(\dagger) \quad
t^{\eta(\lambda^\text{op})} \cdot \big[n \big]! \cdot \prod_{\Box \, \in \, \lambda} \, \big[h(\Box) \big]^{-1} \ = \
\sum_{\stackrel{\scriptstyle \text{standard tableaux}}{\text{$T$ of shape $\lambda$}}} \, t^{\, \eta(\lambda^\text{op}) \,  + \, \text{stat}(T)}
\end{equation}

where $\Box \in \lambda$ indicates a cell of $\lambda$'s Young diagram, $h(\Box)$ is the corresponding hook length of $\Box \in \lambda$, and $\eta(\lambda) = \sum_{i=1}^r (i-1)\lambda_i$
where $\lambda = (\lambda_1, \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_r > 0)$
are the parts of the partition $\lambda \vdash n$; see this posting (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2810707/eta-value-of-a-partition-and-its-meaning) for an elaboration on the nature of the curious $\eta$-statistic. As usual brackets $[\cdot]$ indicate a $t$-number.

A possible approach to the question is to relate the charge statistic
(used in defined the Kostka-Foulkes polynomial) and the statistic $\text{stat}$ in the polynomial expansion on the righthand side of formula $(\dagger)$. Up to a overall factor of $t$, is it possible to get $K_{\lambda, \mu}(t)$ by computing $\text{stat}(T)$ for standard tableaux $T$ of shape $\lambda$ in $\big[\widehat{\scriptstyle 0} \, , \, rT_\mu\big]$ ?

Comment: Very interesting question!

Comment: I agree with Sam, sounds like a really cool question. Also: The published paper is here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316508000861

Comment: Thanks Sam and Per --- It occurred to me that perhaps a better version of the question is whether or not there is a good (statistic preserving) bijection between this interval of standard tableaux of shape $\lambda$ and the semi-standard tableaux of shape $\lambda$ and content $\mu$.

Comment: The question could be related to the notion of cyclage and katabolism: https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/kostkaFoulkes.htm#catabolism